# How to download file one by one in a ListView?

Tags: java, android

I have source code from https://awsrh.blogspot.com/2018/05/volley-glide-tutorial-send-data-and.html

I want to download pdf files, one by one from a server on a button click

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So first you need a normal Button[do this in yourlayoutfile.yml]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
        android:text="Download" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now set a OnClickListener at your Button in youre Activity:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button downloadButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        downloadButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               downloadFile();
            }
        });
    }

    public void downloadFile() {
        //Here put-in youre download stuff
        //so download the file from your server
    }
}
```

Comment: public void downloadFile() {
        //Here put-in youre download stuff <here>
        //so download the file from your server <here>
    }

Comment: i do not know to make it hehe :D

Comment: Try that by place ur link into download file() {here}

Comment: First make a layout file and make a jar file

Comment: Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066114/how-to-download-a-file-after-clicking-a-button-android-studio)

Comment: public void downloadFile() {

        new DownloadTask(CatalogDetailActivity.this,downloadPdf,Utils.downloadPdfUrl);
        new DownloadTask(CatalogDetailActivity.this,downloadPdf,Utils.downloadPdfUrl2);
    }

Comment: i can download file but the file is all same.
do you know how to implements if?
sorry im new

Comment: can u say breifly about what you want to download  so i can try my level best

Comment: i want to make book reader like a google book in playstore
if u want i can send my source code

Comment: dont forget remove ButtonAdapter.class

Answer (score 0):

here is the SO Thread for downloading with progress : [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

and here is another SO Thread for download via android's download manager : [Download Files Using download manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020815/download-files-using-download-manager)

all you need is for loop now :)