# How can I download PDF from Android (Java) on MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, pdf

```php
<?php
// Check if a file has been uploaded
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    // Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        
        // Gather all required data
        $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
        $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
        $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);
        
        // Create the SQL query
        $query = "
                INSERT INTO `file` (
                    `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
                )
                VALUES (
                    '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
                )";
        
        // Execute the query
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);
        
        // Check if it was successfull
        if ($result) {
            echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
        } else {
            echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file' . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. ' . 'Error code: ' . intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
    }
    
    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();
} else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="file.html">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

I used the above code to upload a file on my mysql database using php,html. I want to download this file on my android app. I'm quite blank on this android thing. I have recently just made a login activity using mysql database and I used `jdbc` driver for that purpose. Can anyone guide me how can I download the above uploaded file using android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi brother you can download this pdf using the DownloadService of the android .You just need the location of the file on the server.[This is the link of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020815/download-files-using-download-manager)

Comment: Hey Thanks Jawwad... Can you tell me how can I tell the url of the file when I uploaded it on xampp mysql....

Comment: If you are using localhost then use http://localhost/<Directory of your folder here>